# NullInjectorError: No provider for x

Tags: angular, mat-dialog

Before this `component` was being loaded into `MatDialog` but now the requirement is to load it on some url i.e. `http://localhost:4200/some-url` and when I load this component via url and getting error

> NullInjectorError: No provider for x!

Here is the component that I am trying to load on url.

```
export class MyComponent {
  
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyComponent>,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) { }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the snippet what you have now or what you had previously?

Comment: I have it now. I was loading this component via MatDialog then due to requirement change, trying to load on some url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had component that had `MatDialog` related objects that were responsible for receiving data i.e. `@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any`, something like this:

```
export class MyComponent {
  
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

}
```

Later on, with the requirement change, I had to load this component on some url instead of loading on a dialog. Just removed the dialog related data and it is done.

```
export class MyComponent {
  
  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: @Optional() for hybrid form (dialgo and route)

Answer (score 1):

Include MatDialogModule in imports array in the module in which this component is registered.